# The error "conditional binary operator expected"

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a problem with implementing

```
if

elif ( && ) ||

else

fi
```

This is the particular code:

```
#!/bin/bash

EOSDIR=/eos/user/o/user/muonDIS/2-5-SBT
OutputFile53=PositionData_1.txt
OutputFile52=out_1.root
OutputFile51=TotData_1.txt

if test -e "$EOSDIR"/5/"$OutputFile51"; then
    echo "File exists and is unbroken. Nothing to do..."
        exit 0
elif [[ test -e "$EOSDIR"/5/"$OutputFile52" && [ $(stat -c %s "$EOSDIR"/5/"$OutputFile52") -lt 504 ] ]] || [[ test -e "$EOSDIR"/5/"$OutputFile53" ]]; then
    echo "Files are either broken or absent. New files will be generated"

else
  echo "Go away"
fi
```

It says

> ./t.sh: line 11: conditional binary operator expected ./t.sh: line 11:

> syntax error near `-e' ./t.sh: line 11:` elif [[ test -e

> "$EOSDIR"/5/"$OutputFile52" && [ $(stat -c %s

> "$EOSDIR"/5/"$OutputFile52") -lt 504 ] ]] || pp test -e

> "$EOSDIR"/5/"$OutputFile53" ]]; then'

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Use either `[[` or `test`, not both.

Comment: If you aren't going to write an answer _as an answer_, go ahead and delete the question. Answers do not belong in questions; if you want to add your own you should use the "Add an Answer" button, and write it in such a way as to be useful to other people having the same problem.